# PERL and HTML Forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms, perl

I am learning Perl, and I would like some help with forms.
I have my basic form HTML code.

```html
<FORM action="/cgi-bin/test.pl" method="POST">
 First Name: <input type="text" name="fName"><br>
 Last Name: <input type="text" name="lName">

 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</FORM>
```

And my PERL Code is this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;

my $test = new CGI();
my $fName = "Me";
my $lName = "Bill";

print $test->header("text/html"),$test->start_html("PERL Test");
print $test->h1("Hello, ",$fName, $lName);
print $test->end_html;
```

What I want to do , have the variable fName and lName equal to the names entered into the form, not the default "Me" and "Bill" that I have in there right now.

Comment: **Warning**: [CGI.pm is deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE)

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: NB: [There is no such thing as PERL](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using CGI.pm, use [the `param` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#Fetching-the-value-or-values-of-a-single-named-parameter).

```
my $fName = $test->param("fName");
```

Note that CGI.pm is obsolete and you should use [a modern replacement](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) which will have its own API for reading POST data.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm,  now I can keep playing around with this code to really get the hang of it!

Comment: @Cecily: Did you not read the bit where Quentin said "CGI.pm is obsolete and you should use a modern replacement"? Playing around with this code is a waste of time. Look at PSGI and modern Perl web frameworks instead.